# How to combine 4 arrays together of different sizes so that the resultant array's elements alternates between each of the 4 array's elements

Tags: php

Hard to put a descriptive title to this which is easy to understand so I will try in more depth here. Say I have 4 arrays of different sizes, a1, a2, a3 and a4 which I want to combine into the array SUM.

I want SUM[0] to be a1[0], SUM[1] to be a2[0], SUM[2] to be a3[0], SUM[3] to be a4[0] and then SUM[4] to be a1[1] and so on.

A tricky thing to consider is the arrays are different sizes.

edit: if any array a1,a2,a3,a4 terminates, just move onto the next one - sorry for not making this clear

Comment: What if any of this array terminates? Have to place however an "empity" element or just an element of the "next" array?

Comment: if any array terminates, just move onto the next one - sorry for not making this clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a1=array(1,2,3);
$a2=array(4,5,6,7,8,9);
$a3=array(10,11);
$a4=array(12,13,14,15);
$maxlen = max(count($a1), count($a2), count($a3), count($a4));
$a = array($a1, $a2, $a3, $a4);
$SUM = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxlen; $i++) {
    foreach ($a as $arr) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $arr)) {
            $SUM[] = $arr[$i];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($SUM);
```

OUTPUT:

array(15) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(10)
  [3]=>
  int(12)
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(5)
  [6]=>
  int(11)
  [7]=>
  int(13)
  [8]=>
  int(3)
  [9]=>
  int(6)
  [10]=>
  int(14)
  [11]=>
  int(7)
  [12]=>
  int(15)
  [13]=>
  int(8)
  [14]=>
  int(9)
}

Comment: Suresh 'i' should be '$i' in the for condition

Comment: +1 I would use `array_key_exists` to check if a key is there, in case of array elements with `null` in it :)